# Difference between wp_remote_post and wp_safe_remote_post

Tags: http-api, wp-remote-post

The documentation for `wp_remote_post` [says](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post)

> In many cases you may be better served with `wp_safe_remote_post`

Looking at the source code, the only line that's different between the two is that `wp_safe_remote_post` has this:

`$args['reject_unsafe_urls'] = true;`

[This article](https://websupporter.net/blog/wp_remote_get-vs-wp_safe_remote_get-2/) was the best explanation I found, which seems to indicate that the only time I should use `wp_remote_post` is when I am making a remote call to my own site.

So is there ever any other situation in which I would want to use `wp_remote_post` or should I always stick with `wp_safe_remote_post`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So is there ever any other situation in which I would want to use wp_remote_post or should I always stick with wp_safe_remote_post?

The two functions are exactly the same, except [`wp_safe_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_remote_post/) sets the `reject_unsafe_urls` argument to true. That argument causes the URL to be passed through [`wp_http_validate_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_http_validate_url/) in [`WP_Http::request()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Http/request/).

From that function, we see that there are a few use cases where you would need to use `wp_remote_post()` instead of `wp_safe_remote_post()`.

1. If you are using a protocol that is not http or https.*
2. If you need to pass a user or pass in the URL.
3. If you are posting to the localhost.**
4. If you need to use a port other than 80, 443, or 8080.

It's also possible to use the [`http_request_reject_unsafe_urls`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/http_request_reject_unsafe_urls/) filter to  pass URLs through `wp_http_validate_url()` in an HTTP request whether `wp_safe_remote_post()` or `wp_remote_post()` is called.

[*] If `reject_unsafe_urls` is not set, the URL is still passed though [`wp_kses_bad_protocol()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_bad_protocol/) and the allowed protocols are http, https, and ssl.

[**] It's possible to use `wp_safe_remove_post()` to the localhost by using the `http_request_host_is_external` filter and returning a truthy value.

Answer (score 2):

the *_safe_* functions are kind of a late attempt at input sanitation, something that should have happened long before the code have reached that point. (at that point the request will fail without any ability to notify a user that there is a configuration problem he should resolve).

You should probably always use them, and be ready to handle the situations in which they fail due to you trying to access anything which do not have "basic" url format and uses the most common port numbers.

Answer (score 0):

What a question? You found all interested information.

`wp_safe_remote_post()` function comment says

> Retrieve the raw response from a safe HTTP request using the POST method.    This function is ideal when the HTTP request is being
>   made to an arbitrary  URL. 
>   The URL is validated to avoid redirection
>   and request forgery attacks.

I think always should use `wp_safe_remote_post`. Its safe.

Comment: My question is at the end, "Is there ever a situation in which I would want to use `wp_remote_post`?" But it sounds like the answer is "no" :)